# How can i write values in a column using comma

Tags: java, jmeter

As per my jmeter test plan,i am saving following information into a csv file using Beanshell PostProcessor

```
   username = vars.get("username");
   password = vars.get("password");
   f = new FileOutputStream("/path/user_details.csv", true);
   p = new PrintStream(f); 
   this.interpreter.setOut(p); 
   print(username + "," + password);
   f.close()
```

How can i save those values into a single column using comma (username,password)

Answer (score 0):

Put double quotes around the entire string, so that the comma will be part of a single data item's value, rather than a value separator.

In practice the character you use for the column separator, and the characters you use as a delimiter, are configurable, by a CSV library (which, should really almost always be used instead of trying to get the syntax details right on your own).